# Access denied to S3 via TaskCat

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I want to use Taskcat for my deployments. Everything is nice, except (as always) the permissions. I created a bucket for my templates, which is referred to in the config files. I call `taskcat test run` and after the template is uploaded to my bucket I receive an error, that the `stack creation` failed due to  `S3 error: Access Denied`.

Since I'm able to upload the template via TaskCat, I have the correct permission with my account. Do I need to add a bucket permission, that Cloudformation can access the bucket?

The error code:

```
 _            _             _   
| |_ __ _ ___| | _____ __ _| |_ 
| __/ _` / __| |/ / __/ _` | __|
| || (_| \__ \   < (_| (_| | |_ 
 \__\__,_|___/_|\_\___\__,_|\__|
                                

version 0.9.23
[WARN   ] : ---
[WARN   ] : Linting detected issues in: mypath/template.yml
[WARN   ] :     line 14 [2001] [Check if Parameters are Used] Parameter AZone3 not used.
[INFO   ] : Will not delete bucket created outside of taskcat task-cat-bucket
[ERROR  ] : ClientError An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: S3 error: Access Denied
For more information check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html
Exception ignored in: <function Pool.__del__ at 0x7f9593cec790>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in __del__
    self._change_notifier.put(None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 368, in put
    self._writer.send_bytes(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 200, in send_bytes
    self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 411, in _send_bytes
    self._send(header + buf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 368, in _send
    n = write(self._handle, buf)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Exception ignored in: <function Pool.__del__ at 0x7f9593cec790>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in __del__
    self._change_notifier.put(None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 368, in put
    self._writer.send_bytes(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 200, in send_bytes
    self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 411, in _send_bytes
    self._send(header + buf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 368, in _send
    n = write(self._handle, buf)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are launching the `CloudFormation Stack` via the Console, the user you are logged in with, its credentials are used for all the operations around.

When you say you can upload to the S3 bucket doesn't directly translate to you can download objects as well.

So check your [configured credentials](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/taskcat#requirements) if you have the necessary permissions for the operation.